# execute with applying media query orientation and max width together

Tags: css

I have the code below, but I only want it to execute below a window width of 600px. So I want .shown-modal to be displayed when the window width is below 600 px and in portrait mode together. If not both of these, then it must not be shown. How can I do this? `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 599px) and (orientation:portrait){}`
 does not seem to work.

```
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    .shown-modal {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 599px) and (orientation:portrait) {}
```

Try fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a7g605en/2/ you can change the width and height of the visible area. Instead of hiding I changed the colors from green to orange and viceversa. hope it helps

[image]

```css
h1:before {
  content: 'Landscape ';
}

.shown-modal {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width: 599px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    h1:before {
        content: 'Portrait ';
    }
    
    .shown-modal {
        display: block;
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Mode</h1>

<div class="shown-modal">

</div>
```

Comment: thank you, @caramba, however it does not seem to make a difference what number I use in min-device-width. It seems that min-device-width and orientation are not both linked in order to make the color change. I want the color to only change when the window has a portrait orientation together with being under 600px wide. if the orientation is portrait but 600px or more wide the color should not change. Nor should it change when the width is correct, but the orientation isn't.

Comment: @Eddy updated the answer and code snippet. Added a title telling the "view mode". Also added a movie showing what I see. So for me this has landscape- and portrait-mode. Am I getting you wrong with what you want?

Comment: thank you so much for helping me in such a good way, @caramba. Can you try something for me please. What happens if you make the window wider than 600 px while still in portrait mode. Is shown.modal then green or not? I want it not to be. I want it only to be green when the window is under 600px wide while in portrait mode. These two conditions must be so for it to be green. If only one of these two conditions is so, shown.modal must not be green.

Comment: @Eddy no, it has to be both: only if less then 600px and in portrait mode it will be green.

Comment: I have updated you JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/a7g605en/4/ I have added a blue div with a width of 599px. So, if the window is wider than the blue div, the shown.modal should never be green. I am trying this with Safari browser on a Mac and I am getting that shown.modal is green when the window is wider than the blue div, as long as it is in portrait mode.

Comment: @Eddy I'm not 100% sure of what you really try to achieve. But maybe then it's better to split the rules `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 599px) and (orientation:portrait) {}` into two rules. Keep in mind then it's like normal CSS so it cascaded from top to bottom. Maybe you need to split that rule into a single one and add another one saying `max-device-width`